# Computing the Jacobian Matrix in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to compute Jacobian Matrix in Tensorflow for the following Network:
but It didn't work with my Neural Network!

I found jacobian Matrix code in https://medium.com/unit8-machine-learning-publication/computing-the-jacobian-matrix-of-a-neural-network-in-python-4f162e5db180

Unfortunately it doesn't work with my network ... the problem message is "ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 51000) for Tensor 'dense_1_input:0', which has shape '(?, 6)'"

I think that is the problem in the loop function inside jacobian_tensorflow function?

```
# Importing some Libraries
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
import tensorflow as tf
# Simulation of some data
np.random.seed (245)
nobs =10000

# Definition normalverteilte Features
x1= np.random.normal(size=nobs ,scale=1) 
x2= np.random.normal(size=nobs ,scale=1) 
x3= np.random.normal(size=nobs ,scale=1) 
x4= np.random.normal(size=nobs ,scale=1) 
x5= np.random.normal(size=nobs ,scale=1) 

# Features
X= np.c_[np.ones((nobs ,1)),x1,x2,x3,x4,x5] 


y= np.cos(x1) + np.sin(x2) + 2*x3 + x4 + 0.01*x5 + np.random.normal(size=nobs , scale=0.01) 

#Learningrate
LR=0.05


# Number of Neurons
Neuron_Out=1
Neuron_Hidden1=64
Neuron_Hidden2=32

#The Activation function
Activate_output='linear' # für letzte Schicht verwende ich linear
Activate_hidden='relu' # unterschied ist Hidden-Layer-Neuronen werden nicht linear transformiert


#The Optimizer
Optimizer= SGD(lr=LR)


# The loss function
loss='mean_squared_error'

# Splitting Data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train , x_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size =0.15, random_state =77)

## Neural Network
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed (245)
# As in Medium Essa
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

#Initialize the ANN
model_ANN= Sequential()

# Hidden Layer-> hier wird Hidden Layer definiert-> Anzahl der Neuronen hier sind 64, 32
# input ist 6 (also 1,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)-> one is the first column in X Matrix
model_ANN.add(Dense(Neuron_Hidden1, activation=Activate_hidden, input_shape=(6,), use_bias=True))
model_ANN.add(Dense(Neuron_Hidden2, activation=Activate_hidden, use_bias=True))

#Output Layer-> hier wird Output-Layer defniniert
model_ANN.add(Dense(Neuron_Out, activation=Activate_output,use_bias=True))
model_ANN.summary()

#Fit the model
history_ANN=model_ANN.fit(
x_train, # training data
y_train, # training targets
epochs=125)


def jacobian_tensorflow(x):    
    jacobian_matrix = []
    for m in range(Neuron_Out):
        # We iterate over the M elements of the output vector
        grad_func = tf.gradients(model_ANN.output[:, m], model_ANN.input)
        gradients = sess.run(grad_func, feed_dict={model_ANN.input: x.reshape((1, x.size))})
        jacobian_matrix.append(gradients[0][0,:])

    return np.array(jacobian_matrix)

#Jacobian matrix computation
def jacobian_tensorflow(x):    
    jacobian_matrix = []
    for m in range(Neuron_Out):
        # We iterate over the M elements of the output vector
        grad_func = tf.gradients(model_ANN.output[:, m], model_ANN.input)
        gradients = sess.run(grad_func, feed_dict={model_ANN.input: x.reshape((1, x.size))})
        jacobian_matrix.append(gradients[0][0,:])

    return np.array(jacobian_matrix)

jacobian_tensorflow(x_train)
```

How I could use Jacobian Computation Function for my Network?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code to fix the error and now its working. There were few errors like compile statement missing, function defined twice and forcing the reshape of input for the Dense layer even though the shape was good for `feed_dict` in `jacobian_tensorflow` function. Have added comments in the code for changes.

**Fixed Code -**

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
# Importing some Libraries
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
import tensorflow as tf
# Simulation of some data
np.random.seed (245)
nobs =10000

# Definition normalverteilte Features
x1= np.random.normal(size=nobs ,scale=1) 
x2= np.random.normal(size=nobs ,scale=1) 
x3= np.random.normal(size=nobs ,scale=1) 
x4= np.random.normal(size=nobs ,scale=1) 
x5= np.random.normal(size=nobs ,scale=1) 

# Features
X= np.c_[np.ones((nobs ,1)),x1,x2,x3,x4,x5] 


y= np.cos(x1) + np.sin(x2) + 2*x3 + x4 + 0.01*x5 + np.random.normal(size=nobs , scale=0.01) 

#Learningrate
LR=0.05


# Number of Neurons
Neuron_Out=1
Neuron_Hidden1=64
Neuron_Hidden2=32

#The Activation function
Activate_output='linear' # für letzte Schicht verwende ich linear
Activate_hidden='relu' # unterschied ist Hidden-Layer-Neuronen werden nicht linear transformiert


#The Optimizer
Optimizer= SGD(lr=LR)


# The loss function
loss='mean_squared_error'

# Splitting Data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train , x_test , y_train , y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size =0.15, random_state =77)

## Neural Network
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed (245)
# As in Medium Essa
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

#Initialize the ANN
model_ANN= Sequential()

# Hidden Layer-> hier wird Hidden Layer definiert-> Anzahl der Neuronen hier sind 64, 32
# input ist 6 (also 1,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)-> one is the first column in X Matrix
model_ANN.add(Dense(Neuron_Hidden1, activation=Activate_hidden, input_shape=(6,), use_bias=True))
model_ANN.add(Dense(Neuron_Hidden2, activation=Activate_hidden, use_bias=True))

#Output Layer-> hier wird Output-Layer defniniert
model_ANN.add(Dense(Neuron_Out, activation=Activate_output,use_bias=True))
model_ANN.summary()

# Added the compile statement
model_ANN.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=Optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

#Fit the model
history_ANN=model_ANN.fit(
x_train, # training data
y_train, # training targets
epochs=125)

#Jacobian matrix computation
def jacobian_tensorflow(x):    
    jacobian_matrix = []
    for m in range(Neuron_Out):
        # We iterate over the M elements of the output vector
        grad_func = tf.gradients(model_ANN.output[:, m],model_ANN.input)
        gradients = sess.run(grad_func, feed_dict={model_ANN.input: x})  # Removed x.reshape((1, x.size)) as reshape is not required bcoz dense accepts the shape
        jacobian_matrix.append(gradients[0][0,:])

    return np.array(jacobian_matrix)

jacobian_tensorflow(x_train)
```

**Output -**

```
/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py:1750: UserWarning: An interactive session is already active. This can cause out-of-memory errors in some cases. You must explicitly call `InteractiveSession.close()` to release resources held by the other session(s).
  warnings.warn('An interactive session is already active. This can '
Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 64)                448       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 32)                2080      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 33        
=================================================================
Total params: 2,561
Trainable params: 2,561
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 82us/step - loss: 0.1999 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0501 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0277 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0219 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0190 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0114 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 78us/step - loss: 0.0138 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0092 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0072 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0073 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 11/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0065 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 12/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0070 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 13/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 78us/step - loss: 0.0055 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 14/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 78us/step - loss: 0.0055 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 15/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0055 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 16/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0057 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 17/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0045 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 18/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0052 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 19/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0055 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 20/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0040 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 21/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0045 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 22/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0040 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 23/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 78us/step - loss: 0.0041 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 24/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0044 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 25/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0037 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 26/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 78us/step - loss: 0.0046 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 27/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0042 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 28/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0039 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 29/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 78us/step - loss: 0.0037 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 30/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0042 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 31/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0033 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 32/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0032 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 33/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 78us/step - loss: 0.0033 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 34/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0038 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 35/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 78us/step - loss: 0.0035 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 36/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 78us/step - loss: 0.0032 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 37/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0032 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 38/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 78us/step - loss: 0.0032 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 39/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0032 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 40/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0028 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 41/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0032 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 42/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 77us/step - loss: 0.0029 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 43/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0029 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 44/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0029 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 45/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0028 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 46/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0031 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 47/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0025 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 48/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0022 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 49/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0027 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 50/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0028 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 51/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0024 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 52/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 78us/step - loss: 0.0024 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 53/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0023 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 54/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 78us/step - loss: 0.0026 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 55/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0023 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 56/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0020 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 57/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 78us/step - loss: 0.0024 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 58/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0022 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 59/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0021 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 60/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 78us/step - loss: 0.0022 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 61/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0020 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 62/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0022 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 63/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0022 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 64/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 82us/step - loss: 0.0023 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 65/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0023 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 66/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0018 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 67/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0021 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 68/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0020 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 69/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0020 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 70/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0018 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 71/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0019 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 72/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0018 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 73/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0018 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 74/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0018 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 75/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0019 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 76/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0018 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 77/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 83us/step - loss: 0.0016 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 78/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0019 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 79/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0019 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 80/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0016 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 81/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0018 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 82/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0017 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 83/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0017 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 84/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0016 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 85/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 82us/step - loss: 0.0017 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 86/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0017 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 87/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 83us/step - loss: 0.0017 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 88/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0016 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 89/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 82us/step - loss: 0.0016 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 90/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0018 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 91/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0015 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 92/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 82us/step - loss: 0.0014 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 93/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0016 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 94/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0016 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 95/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 83us/step - loss: 0.0014 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 96/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0014 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 97/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0016 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 98/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0015 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 99/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0014 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 100/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0015 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 101/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0014 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 102/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 82us/step - loss: 0.0015 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 103/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0013 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 104/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0014 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 105/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0013 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 106/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0012 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 107/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 82us/step - loss: 0.0014 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 108/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0012 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 109/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0013 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 110/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0012 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 111/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0012 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 112/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 113/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0014 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 114/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 115/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0012 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 116/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 82us/step - loss: 0.0013 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 117/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0013 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 118/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 82us/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 119/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 79us/step - loss: 0.0012 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 120/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0012 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 121/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 122/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 123/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 82us/step - loss: 0.0012 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 124/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 81us/step - loss: 0.0011 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 125/125
8500/8500 [==============================] - 1s 80us/step - loss: 0.0018 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
array([[ 0.6434634 , -0.09752402,  0.8342059 ,  1.6331654 ,  0.82901144,
        -0.00917255]], dtype=float32)
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Ali SY - Hope we have answered your question. Can you please accept and upvote the answer if you are satisfied with the answer.

Comment: Hello do you know how to modified this for tensorflow 2.0. I keep getting the 

module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'InteractiveSession'

Error